# How to load all pages into one page with their templates

Tags: loop, page-template, content

I am learning how to work with Wordpress, and im trying to build my own website in it.

Since my website is a onepages, i would like to be able to load all my pages ( they then count as sections ) to get loaded on the frontpage, with there templates.

i now have a index.php that loops through the pages but doesnt load the page templates and i just cant get it to work, here is my index.php :

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
    <!-- START CONTENT -->

        <?php
            $args = array(
                'sort_order' => 'ASC',
                'sort_column' => 'menu_order', //post_title
                'hierarchical' => 1,
                'exclude' => '',
                'child_of' => 0,
                'parent' => -1,
                'exclude_tree' => '',
                'number' => '',
                'offset' => 0,
                'post_type' => 'page',
                'post_status' => 'publish'
            );
            $pages = get_pages($args);

            //start loop
            foreach ($pages as $page_data) {
                 $content = apply_filters('the_content', $page_data->post_content);
                 $title = $page_data->post_title;
                 $slug = $page_data->post_name;
                 ?>

                 <div class='<?php echo "$slug" ?>'>

                 <?php
                     echo "$content";
                 ?>

                 </div>
         <?php } ?>

     <!-- END CONTENT -->
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

I really hope you guys can help me out!

Comment: While it is possible to pull all of your pages (and loop thru their content) to a single page, using dozens of templates on a single page isn't going to happen.  I suppose a single page of iframes displaying individual pages as if they were one is possible.

Comment: Well i dont know how to properly make a onepager then, any chance you know how to properly make a onepager, so that the user can easily edit all the content ? and is the iframe way not laggy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this exchanging each page name for the page you want to use. I just tested and it seems to work. I'm sure there are downsides (speed for one).

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: OnePager
 */
    <?php get_header(); ?>
    <!-- Page One - How it Works -->
    <section id="section1">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <?php
                $section1 = new WP_Query( 'pagename=how-it-works' );
                while ( $section1->have_posts() ) : $section1->the_post();?>
                <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
                <?php the_content(); ?>
                <?php endwhile;
                wp_reset_postdata();
            ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </section>
    <!-- Page One - Who We Are -->
    <section id="section2">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <?php
                $section2 = new WP_Query( 'pagename=who-we-are' );
                while ( $section2->have_posts() ) : $section2->the_post();?>
                <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
                <?php the_content(); ?>
                <?php endwhile;
                wp_reset_postdata();
            ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </section>
    <!-- Additional Pages Below -->

    <?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Sometimes people (including myself) are so determined on using php with wordpress that they waste a lot of time trying to do things like this when they could have created what ever it was in a fraction of the time by just using html. Wordpress is mainly designed for dynamic content. Where for the most part one-pager sites are usually pretty static.

I've done a few of these one page sites using wordpress and here's what I've tried.
1) Static html in a wordpress template (fastest and easiest)
2) Used a pagebuilder. There are a few out there, most notably Visual Composer that have support for doing this.
3) Advanced Custom Fields

**Personally I liked the advanced custom fields method the most and have used it a couple times to do this. This way you can easily add image fields and text fields without having to worry about what markup the post editor might alter on output.**

```
    <section>
        <h1><?php the_field('banner_h1_title_text'); ?></h1>
        <h2><?php the_field('banner_h2_description_text'); ?></h2>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-default">
            <?php the_field('call_to_action_main_button'); ?>
        </a>
    </section>
```

Or if I'm feeling really lazy I'll use Advanced Custom Fields like above except use it with the [Custom Content Shortcode](https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-content-shortcode/) then you don't have to worry about php at all. It's sort of like mustache.js for wordpress, if you've ever used or heard of that. Here a couple pages I just made using that method ([parallax](http://disputebills.com/) / [sticky-sections](http://mbistaffing.com/privacy/))

Just do whatever is easiest for you. There's nothing wrong with using html for something that is hardly ever edited. Plus if you're doing it for a client, it would give them a reason to keep you around as they would still need your help if they wanted that page changed :)

Comment: to avoid replication why not use get_pages or get_all_page_ids to get all the pages.

Answer (score 1):

Create a directory `page-templates` in your theme for [page templates](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/page-templates/).

Then add your templates there, but omit the calls to `get_header()` and `get_footer()`.

Create a template `default.php` and then all additional templates you might need.

Now write the pages and assign the proper templates.

In your loop do this:

```
foreach ($pages as $page_data)
{
    setup_postdata( $page_data );

    $template = get_post_meta( $page_data->ID, '_wp_page_template', true );

    if ( ! $template )
        $template = 'default';

    locate_template( $template, true, false );
}
```